Maximum Date where products are bigger than zero and less than calculated date
I'm encountering an error while trying to create a custom column in Power Query in Excel. The goal is to implement two tests:

If the "PPL" column value for a row is zero, return the date from the "Date" column.
Subtract the number of days specified in the "n" column from the date in the "Date" column. If the resulting date has a "PPL" value of zero, find the maximum date where "PPL" is greater than zero and the date is less than the calculated date. If no such date exists, return the calculated date.

Here is an Excel version, the reason I'm not using it is because using formulas kills the performance of my worksheet.
=IF(COUNTIF([Date],[@Custom])=0,IF(WEEKDAY([@Custom],1)=1,[@Custom]-1,[@Custom]),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([@Custom],[Date],[PPL],0)),MAXIFS([Date],[Date],"<"&[@Custom],[PPL],">0"),[@Custom]))
PPL is Production Plan
DTP is Delivered to Plan
My issues: Code ends up accidentaly returning dates where production is equal to zero and when I alter the code I end up facing errors like

Expression.Error: We couldn't apply field access to the Date type.
Details:
Value=02/01/2024
Key=Custom

if List.Count(List.Select({[Date]}, each _=[Custom]))=0 then
    if Date.DayOfWeek([Custom])=0 then Date.AddDays([Custom],-1)
    else [Custom]
else
    let 
        CalendarioProducao=List.Transform(List.Distinct(List.Sort(List.Select({[Date]},each [PPL]>0))), each Number.From(_)),
        ProducaoZero=List.Transform(List.Distinct(List.Sort(List.Select({[Date]},each [PPL]=0))), each Number.From(_))
    in
        if List.Contains(ProducaoZero,[Custom]) then
            List.Max(List.Select(CalendarioProducao, each _< Number.From([Custom])))
        else [Custom]

This is the original database



Index
Date
PPL
item
n




0
02/01/2024
356
a
2


1
02/01/2024
356
b
5


2
02/01/2024
356
c
0


3
03/01/2024
673
a
2


4
03/01/2024
673
b
5


5
03/01/2024
673
c
0


6
04/01/2024
73
a
2


7
04/01/2024
73
b
5


8
04/01/2024
73
c
0


9
05/01/2024
404
a
2


10
05/01/2024
404
b
5


11
05/01/2024
404
c
0


12
06/01/2024
76
a
2


13
06/01/2024
76
b
5


14
06/01/2024
76
c
0


15
07/01/2024
0
a
2


16
07/01/2024
0
b
5


17
07/01/2024
0
c
0


18
08/01/2024
0
a
2


19
08/01/2024
0
b
5


20
08/01/2024
0
c
0


21
09/01/2024
0
a
2


22
09/01/2024
0
b
5


23
09/01/2024
0
c
0


24
10/01/2024
0
a
2


25
10/01/2024
0
b
5


26
10/01/2024
0
c
0


27
11/01/2024
413
a
2


28
11/01/2024
413
b
5


29
11/01/2024
413
c
0


30
12/01/2024
419
a
2


31
12/01/2024
419
b
5


32
12/01/2024
419
c
0


33
13/01/2024
92
a
2


34
13/01/2024
92
b
5



This is the expected outcome:



Index
Date
PPL
item
n
Custom
DTP




0
02/01/2024
356
a
2
31/12/2023
30/12/2023


1
02/01/2024
356
b
5
28/12/2023
28/12/2023


2
02/01/2024
356
c
0
02/01/2024
02/01/2024


3
03/01/2024
673
a
2
01/01/2024
01/01/2024


4
03/01/2024
673
b
5
29/12/2023
29/12/2023


5
03/01/2024
673
c
0
03/01/2024
03/01/2024


6
04/01/2024
73
a
2
02/01/2024
02/01/2024


7
04/01/2024
73
b
5
30/12/2023
30/12/2023


8
04/01/2024
73
c
0
04/01/2024
04/01/2024


9
05/01/2024
404
a
2
03/01/2024
03/01/2024


10
05/01/2024
404
b
5
31/12/2023
30/12/2023


11
05/01/2024
404
c
0
05/01/2024
05/01/2024


12
06/01/2024
76
a
2
04/01/2024
04/01/2024


13
06/01/2024
76
b
5
01/01/2024
01/01/2024


14
06/01/2024
76
c
0
06/01/2024
06/01/2024


15
07/01/2024
0
a
2
05/01/2024
05/01/2024


16
07/01/2024
0
b
5
02/01/2024
02/01/2024


17
07/01/2024
0
c
0
07/01/2024
06/01/2024


18
08/01/2024
0
a
2
06/01/2024
06/01/2024


19
08/01/2024
0
b
5
03/01/2024
03/01/2024


20
08/01/2024
0
c
0
08/01/2024
06/01/2024


21
09/01/2024
0
a
2
07/01/2024
06/01/2024


22
09/01/2024
0
b
5
04/01/2024
04/01/2024


23
09/01/2024
0
c
0
09/01/2024
06/01/2024


24
10/01/2024
0
a
2
08/01/2024
06/01/2024


25
10/01/2024
0
b
5
05/01/2024
05/01/2024


26
10/01/2024
0
c
0
10/01/2024
06/01/2024


27
11/01/2024
413
a
2
09/01/2024
06/01/2024


28
11/01/2024
413
b
5
06/01/2024
06/01/2024


29
11/01/2024
413
c
0
11/01/2024
11/01/2024


30
12/01/2024
419
a
2
10/01/2024
06/01/2024


31
12/01/2024
419
b
5
07/01/2024
06/01/2024


32
12/01/2024
419
c
0
12/01/2024
12/01/2024


33
13/01/2024
92
a
2
11/01/2024
11/01/2024


34
13/01/2024
92
b
5
08/01/2024
06/01/2024



Adjustments to code, logic improvements

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What error? What step? Your code does not produce any errors here on your data set.

Still unclear:  You write: "Code returns dates where production is equal to zero" but in your logic statements 1 and 2 you are always returning a date.

This is the issue, it should return the previous date with production bigger than zero, but it returns a date where production is equal to zero

Please show what you expect for results given the data sample you have posted.

Post update providing more details

Your results do not follow your stated logic. 1. If the "PPL" column value for a row is zero, return the date from the "Date" column.  But there are multiple rows where PPL =  0 but the returned date is different. Please review your logic.

Is it valid to assume that PPL will be the same for all rows that have the same date? That is the case in all of your examples.

Also, which is the column you wish to return: DTP or Custom? If DTP, please explain the logic for Index 0 and 10

The code below returns the results you show for your DPT column except for Index 0 and 10 which seem to be returning a date that does not represent a date in the Date column nor the calculated date from computing `[Date] - [n]. Please clarify
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    Tabela2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"PPL", Int64.Type}, {"item", type text}, {"n", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Tabela2, "minus days", each Date.AddDays([Date],-[n]), type date),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "DTP", (r)=> 
        let 
            #"Match Dates" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Date] = r[minus days]),
            #"Filtered" = 
                if 
                    Table.IsEmpty(#"Match Dates") then r[minus days]
                else //match calc date
                    let 
                        minusMatch = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Date] = r[minus days]),
                        PPL = List.Sum(minusMatch[PPL]),
                        #"PPL gt 0" = 
                            if PPL > 0 then r[minus days] 
                                else List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [PPL] > 0 and [Date] < r[minus days])[Date])


                    in #"PPL gt 0"
            
            

        in 
            #"Filtered", type date),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"minus days"})
    
in
    #"Removed Columns"

Data

Results

